# How to use Apache Netbeans 10 binaries on macos high sierra?

Tags: java, macos, apache, netbeans

I have recently downloaded the Apache Netbeans 10 binaries from the [Apache Netbeans (Incubating) site](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb100/nb100.html). I extracted the zip file to /Application/netbeans/. But when I try to run `/Application/netbeans/bin/netbeans` I get the an error in the terminal: `Unknown option: n` follow by the help message. What I'm missing here? I'm running `java version "11.0.2"`. Please for your help.